# Footer overlay with an image

Tags: html, css

I have a fullscreen cover background and I'm trying to get a footer over it which darkens the background. However I also need to put a picture on top of it which get darkened as well. I've tried to use z-index and sliced image with transparency but it was just blue and it didn't work.

```
#footer {
height: 100px;
opacity: 0.4;
background-color: #000000;
}
html { 
  background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Edit:

I was able to resolve it simply by adding another div element above with a negative margin without the use of z-index at all

```
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    <div id="footer-main">
    <img src="uqu-logo.png">
    <p>Got question? Check our <a href="#">FAQ</a></p>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url('footer-bkg.png');}
#footer-main {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -567px;
    margin-top: -82px;
    position: absolute;
color: white;}
```

Comment: So you have a picture that you want on top of the main background, that your footer will be on top of?  So in order from lowest to highest elements, it would be html background, image, and then footer on top of all of that?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it simply by adding another div element above with a negative margin without the use of z-index at all

```
<div id="footer">
</div>
<div id="footer-main">
<img src="uqu-logo.png">
<p>Got question? Check our <a href="#">FAQ</a></p>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url('footer-bkg.png');}
#footer-main {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -567px;
    margin-top: -82px;
    position: absolute;
color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
#footer { position: relative; z-index: 9999; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is this picture going? What div is it going into? Because right now if I'm understanding correctly, you just want a box which is on a layer above the background which has reduced opacity. [**[jsFiddle]**](http://jsfiddle.net/3kNSL/) Which it is technically already doing.

Can you give us the HTML markup as well? Or input it in a jsFiddle so we can see where the problem is.

Also if Z-indexes weren't working, make sure you are assigning a z-index to every element and not only the #footer.

```
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 999;
}
#img_div {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Black-bird. I actually resolved it by adding a div below with a negative margin - I'll post the details in the question itself. thanks